# Query apache for how many responses (of each status code) it has served out for better monitoring & graphing?

Tags: apache-2.4, monitoring, prometheus

I have several apache web servers installed from standard Ubuntu 18.04/20.04/etc. I want to monitor how many requests they are handeling. I am now looking into prometheus & grafana after 15+ years of just “putting up” with nagios & munin.

Is there anyway for apache to report “Since the server was started, I have handled X 200 requests, Y 404 requests, etc etc”? `mod_status` doesn't report this. I think if I can get access to these stats, then I can graph how many people are using the web server, and possibly detect some failures (by looking for lots of 500s).

Answer (score 2):

You have to stream apache logs into an aggregator, like Elasticsearch. After that, you should to build your aggregations in your dashboard.